# If i forked a repo and then cloned my fork, what is the default value of an upstream (-u thing)?

Tags: git, github, version-control

Not sure what the default value of -u is if i forked and then cloned a repo. Would it be related to the repo that i forked from or the repo i  cloned from?

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Git doesn't know or care about GitHub forks.  The `-u` flag to Git is just that—a flag to a Git command—so the presence or absence of a GitHub fork isn't relevant here.

What Git *does* understand is the idea of a "remote": a short name for a URL.  Since GitHub's fork operation creates a new, separate repository with a new, separate URL, you can *add* the "GitHub side upstream" *as* a second remote.  That is:

- on GitHub, you fork repository **T** ("theirs") to repository **M** ("mine");
- on your laptop, clone **M** to **M2**, so that `origin` in **M2** refers to **M**;
- on your laptop, in **M2**, run `git remote add name url` where *`name`* is whatever name you want to use for **T**, and *`url`* is the URL for **T**;

and now you can run `git fetch name` to create and update remote-tracking names<sup>1</sup> of the form `name/branch-name-from-T` in **M2**, after getting from **T** any commits that **T** has that **M2** lacks.

If you have permission to push directly to **T**, you may now do so with `git push name refspec` (remember that *`name`* here is your name in **M2** *for* **T**)—but if you have permission to push directly to **T**, we might wonder why you bothered creating **M** in the first place.  So we might *assume* that you *do not* have this permission, in which case you will push commits *to* **M**, with `git push origin refspec`.  In general, the *`refspec`* you use here will simply be one of your own branch names within **M2**.  For instance, after creating a branch named `feature/rex-racer`, you might `git push origin feature/rex-racer`.

To *set the upstream* of your branch `feature/rex-racer` to your own newly-created remote-tracking name `origin/feature/rex-racer` at this point—now that `origin/feature/rex-racer` exists, in other words—you would subsequently run:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/feature/rex-racer feature/rex-racer
```

(you can drop the final `feature/rex-racer` from this command *if* this is your *current branch*).

The `-u` argument to `git push` is simply a way to avoid having to type in the subsequent `git branch --set-upstream-to` command.  It means: *Hey Git, after this `git push` command succeeds—if it does succeed—run the obvious corresponding `git branch --set-upstream-to` command*.  The "obvious" command is to take whatever remote-tracking name you just created or updated and stick it into the `<thing>` part of `--set-upstream-to=<thing>`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Modern Git documentation calls these things *remote-tracking branch names*.  But once you have one—e.g., the `origin/feature/rex-racer` in the example here—if you try to `git switch origin/feature/rex-racer`, Git tells you that this isn't a *branch* name.  Indeed, it is *not* a branch name.  When is a branch name not a branch name?  When it's a remote-tracking branch name.  Why not drop the word *branch* entirely and just call this a *remote-tracking name*, then?  [Well, nobody ever said Git's *documentation* was a model of clarity...](https://git-man-page-generator.lokaltog.net/) (parody site).